# How to use " UserPanel Layout " in " Main Layout "?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a layout ("_UserLayout.cshtml") in **User_Panel area** :

[Click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOqV0.png)

**Just like what we do in the Admin_Panel. ( each button in sidebar has a ActionResult )**

But the problem is that I want this layout to be inside the main layout of the site. That is, the user panel layout is in the content section of the site :

[Click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ971.jpg)

**Exactly like the attached photo.**

**How can i do it in Asp.Net Core?**

I used main layout in "_ViewStart.cshtml" of userpanel area, **But it does not make sense to repeat the user layout (for example : sidebar) every time in all views ...**

The user panel of many sites is like this :

[Click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cmVY.png)

What is the best way to do this?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use other layouts as `Layout` in any layout page. For example:

Site main layout (`_BaseLayout.cshtml`):

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Admin layout (`_AdminLayout.cshtml`):

```
@{
    Layout = "_BaseLayout";
}
<!-- Put markups which are common to all admin pages -->
@RenderBody()
```

Userpanel Layout (`_UserLayout.cshtml`)

```
@{
    Layout = "_BaseLayout";
}
<!-- Put markups which are common to all user pages pages (side panel etc) -->
@RenderBody()
```

You can build layouts like this. And then use this in all user pages like:
A sample user page(`UserAccount.cshtml`)

```
@{
    Layout = "_UserLayout";
}
<!--  page markups -->
```